# Element Tree error on parse after creating xml via element tree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

Why can't the xml created by this code be parsed by python or read?

I have a chunk of code that is writing an xml file:

```
idlist = list(set([d['type'] for d in List]))                   ##create list of all ID numbers
idlist.sort()
root = ET.Element("MarketData")
for i in idlist:                                                ##iterate over every ID number
    doc = ET.SubElement(root, 'Item', typeID=str(i))            ##create child for current ID number
    tList = list(filter(lambda x: x['type'] == i, List))        ##make a list of all orders for current ID
    sList = list(filter(lambda x: x['buy'] == False, tList))    ##create list of only sell orders
    bList = list(filter(lambda x: x['buy'] == True, tList))     ##create list of only by orders
    spl = list([d['price'] for d in sList])                     ##create list of sell prices
    bpl = list([d['price'] for d in bList])                     ##create list of buy prices
    if not spl:                                                 ##null case
        spl = [-1]
    if not bpl:                                                 ##null case
        bpl = [-1]
    sp = min(spl)                                               ##find min sell price
    bp = max(bpl)                                               ##find max buy price
    ET.SubElement(doc, 'Sell Price').text = str(sp)             ##write sell price to child as string under new sub-element
    ET.SubElement(doc, 'Buy Price').text = str(bp)              ##write buy price to branch as string under new sub-element
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("MarketData.xml")                                    ##write xml tree to final xml file
```

it executes fine, and my test code with identical xml logic writes a perfectly readable file but when i create a file using this code it is unreadable and can't be parsed by ElementTree.

From python I get: "xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 41".

From Firefox i get: "error on line 1 at column 42: Specification mandate value for attribute Price".

The first chuck of the xml (when opened via np++) is:

```
<MarketData><Item typeID="18"><Sell Price>64.92</Sell Price><Buy Price>53.31</Buy Price></Item><Item typeID="19"><Sell Price>36999.99</Sell Price><Buy Price>3502.03</Buy Price></Item>
```

I'm at a complete loss... any suggestions?

note: I'm not a coder, I do this for fun while playing a game so please don't beat me up too hard for anything...

Comment: After posting I noticed the color coding on the xml which lead me to try something out. It seem that the by setting the 'name' to 'sell price' causes the xml to view 'price' as an attribute that hasn't been assigned a value. By changing the name to 'sell_price' the problem is eliminated. I am surprised to find that changing it to 'price' ALSO fixes the issue. Anyone able to explain what is going on here? I'm a bit confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have an element name with spaces in it, such as `Sell Price`. A start-tag such as `<Sell Price>` (or an empty-element tag like `<Sell Price />`) is not complete. It is interpreted as the element `Sell` having an attribute `Price` without a value assigned to it. And that is illegal.

Unfortunately, ElementTree allows you to create bad output exhibiting this error. Here is a small demonstration (tested with Python 2.7.13):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("root")
ET.SubElement(root, 'Sell Price')
print ET.tostring(root)
```

This program outputs `<root><Sell Price /></root>`, which is ill-formed.

If you use [lxml](http://lxml.de) instead of ElementTree, you get the correct behaviour (an exception is thrown):

```
from lxml import etree as ET

root = ET.Element("root")
ET.SubElement(root, 'Sell Price')
print ET.tostring(root)
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "error.py", line 6, in <module>
    ET.SubElement(root, 'Sell Price')
  File "src\lxml\lxml.etree.pyx", line 3112, in lxml.etree.SubElement (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:75599)
  File "src\lxml\apihelpers.pxi", line 183, in lxml.etree._makeSubElement (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:16962)
  File "src\lxml\apihelpers.pxi", line 1626, in lxml.etree._tagValidOrRaise (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:32556)
ValueError: Invalid tag name u'Sell Price'
```

Comment: while looking for a module to do the xml elementTree seemed to be the most popular. what are the advantages/disadvantages of lxml vs ElementTree?

Comment: lxml can be regarded as a "superset" of ElementTree. The basic API is the same, but lxml has many more features. A disadvantage is that it is not part of the Python standard library and has to be installed separately.

Comment: See also this bug, which was resolved as "won't fix": https://bugs.python.org/issue5166.

Answer (score 2):

Element names can't contain blanks. For instance, you could replace occurrences of 'Buy Price' with 'Buy_Price'.  This version of your file opens successfully.

```
<MarketData>
<Item typeID="18">
<Sell_Price>64.92</Sell_Price>
<Buy_Price>53.31</Buy_Price>
</Item>
<Item typeID="19">
<Sell_Price>36999.99</Sell_Price>
<Buy_Price>3502.03</Buy_Price>
</Item>
</MarketData>
```

Comment: why is that though, since it's a string? really just trying to understand now :)

does xml just not like white space?

Comment: Do not make the mistake of treating XML as a free-form text. XML is a markup language that adheres to the W3C industry specifications of which: *the first character of a Name MUST be a NameStartChar, and any other characters MUST be NameChars;* which does not include whitespace under [2.3 Common Syntactic Constructs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn).

Comment: Put simply, writing xml is like coding in any programming language. The rules for creating names tend to be quite strict. If the rules were loosened then the constructs would become more ambiguous and this would have various consequences: it would take more work to make them less ambiguous, it would take more resources to process them and things written in xml would be less useful because they could not be processed so efficiently.

Comment: @Parfait: The problem that I think prompted the question is that ElementTree is not strict enough. It does not enforce the rule that whitespace is not allowed in element names. It should not be possible to create an "XML" document such as `<root><Sell Price /></root>`. But unfortunately it is. See my answer.